# column-layout messed up when a hidden element becomes visible

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I have a few div’s, I’ve arranged them in 3 columns with this code:

```
display: inline-block; width: 33%;
```

Every div has a button.  If you click on the button a hidden paragraph inside the div is shown. For this I’ve used the .toggle() function (jquery) with this css-code:

```
p {
   display: none;
   width: 100%;
   height: 4em; 
   overflow-y: scroll; 
   overflow-x: none; 
   border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

My problem is: when I click the button and the paragraph of the div is shown, the position of the other div's also changes (they all move down, really messing up the lay-out).

What I want is: the paragraph should only push down the div's in the same column. The position of the div's in the other 2 columns should stay the same.

Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like [that](https://jsfiddle.net/gq2tt2gm/2/).
You should surround your 3 paragraph div with an other to not mess up the layout.

```
<div>
  <div class="paragraph" id="paragraph1">
    <p>
      1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraph" id="paragraph2">
    <p>
      2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraph" id="paragraph3">
    <p>
      3Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```